# Order on integer value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an integer column "level". I want to order on level by doing this in the controller:

```
@leagues = League.all.order('level')
```

This results in 1, 10, 2, 3 as results, where I would expect 1, 2, 3, 10 as results.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you created the column as a string in the DB ... if it was a int, you'd get 1, 2, 3, 10 ... at least with MySQL!

Comment: Marcelo is right. I don't even know how `League.all.order` doesn't send error, it does for me. Different version of Rails I guess

Comment: You're right, it was a varchar value in the DB, stupid mistake of me!

Answer (score 1):

Try only **League.order('level')**